# React hooks: How to write variables in functional components that in class components were initialized in the constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using uppy with React and they normally initialize uppy as a global variable. In React, they allow to do this instead:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.uppy = Uppy()
      .use(Transloadit, {})
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.uppy.close()
  }

  render () {
    return <StatusBar uppy={this.uppy} />
  }
}
```

How do I write this in a functional component with hooks? The naive approach would be the following (didn't expect it to work after reading [this issue](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1085)):

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const uppy = Uppy()
    .use(Transloadit, {})

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => uppy.close()
  })

  return <StatusBar uppy={uppy} />
}
```

PS: It needs to be done inside of the functional component because I'm using some props in an `uppy.use` method.

Comment: [*"you can create it outside the function ... \[or\] use a class component with lifecycle methods"*](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1085#issuecomment-426978634). Hooks/functional components aren't mandatory and are interoperable with class components, just use a class component for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Variables in functional components can be initialized using `useRef` hook (read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)). Also since you only want to run the cleanup function on unmounting and not on every re-render, you should pass an empty `[]` as the second argument to `useEffect`

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const uppy = useRef(Uppy()
    .use(Transloadit, {}))

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => uppy.current.close()
  }, [])

  return <StatusBar uppy={uppy.current} />
}
```

Comment: None of the suggested solutions work. I found [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) in the React docs, indicating that this answer is correct. But when using the uppy library, it does not work. So, I guess this proves that there is no 100% equivalent way to replace instance variables with hooks.

Comment: What problem do you face when using the above solution. I updated my answer too. Please check

Comment: Hey, it works now. And you know what, it makes sense. Before, without passing `[]`, any state update ran `close`, but now it only cleans up on unmounting (just like in the class component). Thanks. :)

Comment: Hmm, what I did was to put the creation inside the `useEffect`. (Yes, you can still use `const` for the reference.) I guess the version on the answer also works. Does the initial value expression get executed when the component is mounted?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve like this.

```
> const MyComponent = (props) => {   let uppy;
> 
>   useEffect(() => {
>     uppy = Uppy()
>     .use(Transloadit, {});
>     return () => uppy.close()   }, [])
> 
>   return <StatusBar uppy={uppy} /> }
```

Comment: I think the reason why it doesn't work is that the `render` method runs before `useEffect` runs, so the `StatusBar` component finds an `uppy` that is still `undefined`. I think `useEffect` never blocks `render` which is different from `componentDidMount` which can block rendering (but just if there are synchronous calls to `setState` made in there, at least that's my understanding).