# How do you use Library Constructer outside of a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, constructor, scope, cdn

I am using a library in my React app (they do not have a node package) that I am bringing in on a CDN in the `<head>`.

I am using the `useEffect` hook to prevent it from calling the library constructor over and over, which just breaks it. But I cannot get the library to show itself outside of the hook.

example...

```js
export default function ReactComponent(){
   let tdna = undefined;

   useEffect(() => {
        tdna = new TypingDNA();
        console.log(tdna)
    }, [])
    
    console.log(tdna)
}
```

The first console log shows the library, and only once as I expected. But my attempt to define it on the globalscope has been futile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks: How to write variables in functional components that in class components were initialized in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392794/react-hooks-how-to-write-variables-in-functional-components-that-in-class-compo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with the `useRef` hook to get a stable value that does not change during subsequent renders

```js
export default function ReactComponent(){
   let tdna = useRef();

   useEffect(() => {
       if (!tdna.current) {
            tdna.current = new TypingDNA();
        }
    }, [tdna])
    
    console.log(tdna.current)
}
```